# how to append to div id

Tags: javascript, html

i know it is easy and silly question but how can i show the lat and lng append into div id instead of giving me on alert.Can i do something like that !!

document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = ("lat: +lat+"lng: " + lng)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<head>


    <script>
        function geolocation(){  
<!--checks if geolocation is available -->
var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true};
watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        <!-- function run if gets the geolocation back -->
function onSuccess(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;


    alert("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + lng);

    }
    <!-- this function run if there is any error in geolocation -->
function onError(error){
    alert("message: " + error.message);

                }
        }
        geolocation();

    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="here"></div>



</body>
```

Comment: You're asking how to make a div using an id you've made? Or how to append somthing to a div? Because I don't see a div being created.

Comment: Is `watchId` the id you want for your div?

Comment: to append to div which is inside <body>.

Comment: `document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;`

Comment: yes brendon .. that is watchId, which shows the current position right...

Comment: Hope that helps, Let me know if my answer wasn't what you were looking for so I can fix it if necessary.

Comment: get current geolocation and append the coordinates to a div: that was the question. Code suggested by akinuri and many other gives me the lat n lng coords on my phone but the one you have suggested shows only blank page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this: **Edit: Updated HTML**

```
<div id="location"></div>

    <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            geolocation();
        }

        function geolocation(){  
            <!--checks if geolocation is available -->
            var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true};
            watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
                <!-- function run if gets the geolocation back -->
            function onSuccess(position){
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;

                //alert("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + lng);
                document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "lat: " + lat + "lng: " + lng;
            }

            <!-- this function run if there is any error in geolocation -->
                function onError(error){
                alert("message: " + error.message);
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So, I think what you want is this:

```
div = document.getElementById('here');
div.appendChild(watchId);
```

Thats how you append to your particular div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, with the property innerHTML you wrote you should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definetely can. However, the string you provided is not quoted correctly. Don' t you get an exception in console?

```
document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "lat: " + lat + "lng: " + lng;
```

Comment: No that looks fine honestly. Did you run it and it did not work?

Comment: This one? document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = ("lat: +lat+"lng: " + lng)? At least it has odd number of quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can simply do this:

```
$("#here").text("lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng");
```

Or if you want to keep the content of `here` and append the information at the end:

```
$("#here").append("lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng");
```